# Can someone explain how you get false in this function expression?

Tags: javascript

I understand the first part of the `if`, but isn't the second part stating "since 'n' is not equal to zero, return 'n' in the even function modified with the logical NOT(!) operator."?
Doesn't that return 4 if I were to pass 5 as the argument to `fn();`?

```
var fn = function even (n)
{
    if (n === 0)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else 
    {
        return !even(n - 1)
    }    
};

fn(5); //=> false
```

Comment: this function ignores the fact that negative numbers can be even.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not the `even` function is modified with the boolean NOT, but the NOT is applied on the *result* of invoking the `even` function with `n - 1`. Not 4 is returned, but `!(even(4))`.

If we simplify the function to

```
function even(n) { return n==0 || !even(n-1); }
```

we get the following expansion of your call:

```
even(5)
5==0 || !even(5-1)
!even(4)
!(4==0 || !even(4-1))
!!even(3)
!!(3==0 || !even(3-1))
!!!even(2)
!!!(2==0 || !even(2-1))
!!!!even(1)
!!!!(1==0 || !even(1-1))
!!!!!even(0)
!!!!!(0==0 || !even(0-1))
!!!!!(true || !even(0-1))
!!!!!true
!!!!false
!!!true
!!false
!true
false
```

Answer (score 7):

`even(n)` is always the opposite of `even(n-1)`.

As `even(0)` is `true`, `even(1)` is `false` and so on : all multiples of 2 give `true` and odd numbers give `false`.

A simple way to see it might be to log `[0,1,2,3,4,5].map(even)`.

---

Just in case you were really looking for a way to know if a positive integer is even, the solution you show is very very inefficient and the recursion results in a call stack explosion for any big number. Here's a more reasonable solution :

```
function even(n){
    return !(n%2);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think it's best explained by showing what would happen without the `!` in the return. If we have:

```
var fn = function even (n){
  if (n === 0)  return true;
  else return even(n - 1)
}
```

It's always going to return `true`, because it will eventually hit `0`. If we call `fn(3)`, the call stack will look something like this:

```
fn(3)
  -> fn(2)
    -> fn(1)
      -> fn(0)
        true
      true
    true
  true
true
```

The `!` in the recursive call negates the previous value, so the new call stack looks like:

```
fn(3)
  -> fn(2)
    -> fn(1)
      -> fn(0)
        true
      !true
    !(!true)
  !(!(!true))
!(!(!(!true)))
```

`!(!(!(!true))) === true`

Answer (score 0):

This is an inefficient but valid way of recursively calculating whether a positive integer (see note at end) is even. Basically, each time you're checking a non-zero number, you rely on the fact that whether n is even is the same as whether n-1 is not even. So even(5) is the same as !even(4), and !even(4) is the same as !!even(3) (or even(3)). So by the end, you're calculating even(5) as !!!!!even(0). We know even(0) returns true, so since !! negates itself, we're left with !true, or false.

As per the comments - since this is a recursive function that expects to end when it reaches zero, it will cause an infinite recursion if it were given an input value which was a **good** way to check whether a number is even.

Comment: You use the term "valid" fairly loosely. What does the function say when you ask it about `-2` or `1.5`?

Comment: A fair point - there's no error checking, so this will only give correct results given correct input. You're correct that I'm using "valid" in an informal sense rather than a strict technical one.